# Cordova Remote Build on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build, taco

I am encountering a problem trying to build and deploy a cordova app on an iPhone device (latest iOS 9.3). I am worried this may be due to an incompatibility of versions - I do have my doubts about this though. My macbook pro is still running on yosemite (10.10.5) and my xcode version is 7.3.1. However it has been this way ever since I started working on this app, and I am 100% sure that I've also managed to deploy the app on devices which were running on iOS 9.3, with no problems.

Now when running from visual studio using a remotebuild, visual studio is connecting to my macbook using the remote build successfully, steps are happening as usual BUT during the final bit it seems to stop and I get this error log, defining file MDAVSCLI but giving no description nor code:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZWls.jpg

When going to the directory where the taco builds are stored on the mac and opening the xcode project in xcode, I try to run it from there and I get the apparently well known error: Could not find developer disk image.

I've figured this is known to be due to trying to deploy on the latest version of iOS from an older version of xCode. But this doesn't explain why it is suddenly failing to work using the remote build, as this worked up until a month ago or so and it was the same versions of iOS and OSX respectively.

I can't recall anything specific I changed since then. For your info these are the versions of node.js and cordova that Im using:

Node Version 0.12.9
Cordova Version 6.1.1

I am downloading OSX El Capitan (it will take a while) and will then be able to upgrade to the latest version of xCode to. However I am still afraid that this won't solve the problem. I would appreciate your insight and help about this.

___________________________________UPDATE________________________________

I tried installing another app and it managed to built using remote build on the same iOS device, same versions of node, cordova and all. The problem seems to be within the actual app I am developing. What can it be? What can I look for?

___________________________________UPDATE________________________________

An earlier version of the app worked properly too; The changes I did were small code changes such as html, small functionality js changes and css, otherwise, no settings that in my mind could potentially break the app were done; I am attaching the output of the non-working version of the app:

www.we.tl/ZeIw5C4Tvn

Comment: It looks like your last URL is broken, for your build output. Have you tried removing the app from the iOS device and redeploying? Perhaps there's an issue during installation of the app.

Comment: Yes I tried that but still it didn't deploy with the same errors / output

Comment: Go ahead and email me the build output, since I know it's a big file: jomatthi -at- Microsoft -dot- com. We can take a look and see if anything stands out as an issue.

Comment: There may be a bug in our error handling within Visual Studio...to help rule that out I suggest you try running the generated XCode Project directly from XCode and see if that exposes an error or if it works fine.
 
You can find the generated file in the path ~/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/<build number>/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/<project>.xcodeproj. Open that and then launch using the iOS simulator target and see if that works, then let me know here.